# Are there Japanese words for chili peppers which would translate to "Japanese chili pods"?

Tags: words, word-requests, food

What is the Japanese word for "Japanese chili pods", like the ones in the link below?

https://www.mexgrocer.com/9656.html

Comment: I edited my question, hopefully to reduce downvotes...

Comment: This seems to be unrelated to the Japanese language. You can probably ask on Cooking SE.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question related to the Japanese Language.

Comment: @istrasci, this reads to me (currently) as a question about vocabulary.  Is that not related to the Japanese language?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi:  Possibly, but then it would be a translation request, which is also off-topic.  I debated which of the two reasons to choose.

Comment: That's quite a bit of shoehorning you did there, but this square peg still doesn't fit in the round hole. Are Japanese chili pods a Japanese concept? is a weird question. If you accept that they are Japanese, asking if they are a Japanese concept is odd. If you don't accept that they are Japanese, then the question is no longer about the language but the nature of the chilis in the picture. You can always ask questions like these in the chat room.

Comment: @By137 Yes, I can see my question has caused trouble. I bet this is not the first time "Japanese chili pods" have caused such a disagreement! lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several varieties of chili peppers used in Japan: 三鷹 *santaka*, 本鷹 *hontaka* or 鷹の爪 *taka no tsume*, all using the character 鷹 for "hawk" (in particular 鷹の爪 *taka no tsume* lit. means "hawk's claw", because that's what they resemble). The first two are explicitly mentioned on the site you linked and your "Japanese chili pods" actually look very very similar:

[image: taka no tsume]

(from [cookpad entry](https://cookpad.com/cooking_basics/18659) on *taka no tsume*).

Comment: あほんまや、あれ鷹の爪やん・・・　　https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%B7%B9%E3%81%AE%E7%88%AA　`鷹の爪（たかのつめ）は、トウガラシ (Capsicum annuum) の品種。日本では代表的な品種である。` そうなんや。。赤唐辛子を乾燥したやつが鷹の爪やと思ってた

Comment: Thank you both. This is information I do not have in my dictionary or anywhere else. I now have an appreciation why someone would call taka no tsume "Japanese chili peppers" to specify these characteristic peppers. I think the term 唐辛子 that Eirikr uses corresponds to the English "hot pepper" and that there is no common corresponding term to taka no tsume.

Comment: +1 for better intuiting what the OP was looking for!  :D

Answer (score 3):

The general term for chilis in Japanese is 唐辛子【とうがらし】.  Dried goods often use the word 乾燥【かんそう】.

Here's one example from the online shopping site Rakuten:

https://item.rakuten.co.jp/elborracho/chilearbol/

**メキシコ料理用 チレ・アルボル【乾燥唐辛子】**

[image]